# python configparser writes integers within square brackets

Tags: python, configparser

I am reading a config file with Python's ConfigParser (Python 3.4). My values are all integers, e.g.

```
key1 = 11
key2 = 22
```

When I write the config file, after having read it into a Config object, with

```
with open('settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    Config.write(configfile)
```

my file ends up looking like this:

```
key1 = ['11']
key2 = ['22']
```

Why is the file being written like this, and not as it originally was?

```
key1 = 11
key2 = 22
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing list instead of the list's value?

Your should be setting the value, by something like this:

```
config.set('section1', 'key1', key_val_variable)
```

Can you try printing 'key_val_variable'

Please try:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read("settings.ini")

key_var = ['key1']

if not config.has_section('section1'):
   config.add_section('section1')

config.set('section1', 'key1', key_var)
config.set('section1', 'key2', key_var[0])

with open("settings.ini", 'wb') as configfile:
   config.write(configfile)
```

Comment: Actually, this happens even if I just read the ini file and then write it, without setting any values.  My ini file has 888 values in it. The problem seems to be related to the size of the file. If I halve the size of the file to only have 400 or so entries, it works as expected, with values being re-written as 11 instead of ['11']

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. In my long list of 800+ options, I had some duplicate keys, which was corrupting the parsing of the ini file. When I removed the duplicate keys, all worked as expected.